# How to add Backing Field for Gson Expose annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform, gson

Expose - without getter - setter is working

```
@Expose
    var messageId: String? = null
```

I am getting error in below

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'

```
@Expose
    var messageId: String?
        get() = getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID)
        set(value) = putOrIgnore(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, value)
```

I need to annotate Expose to use `GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` How to use Backing field in my Property?

Here is my Model class:

```
@ParseClassName(COMPLEX_MESSAGE_OBJ)
class ComplexMessage : ParseObject() {

    companion object {
        const val COMPLEX_MESSAGE_OBJ = "ComplexMessage"
        const val KEY_MESSAGE_ID = "messageId"
    }

    @Expose
    var messageId: String?
        get() = getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID)
        set(value) = putOrIgnore(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, value)
}
```

Comment: Are you using ParseSDK?

Comment: Yes I am using Parse SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [ParseSDK-Android](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/tree/master/ktx)

below code should help.

```
@Expose
var messageId: String by stringAttribute()
```